# c# application that interact with different type of dbms

Tags: c#

I am developing a c# application that will be able to use all type of DBMS  that user might have installed. I was wondering if there is any library or window API that can interact with all databases such as MySql,MsSql,Sqlite etc!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding but i meant how to interact with all type of database

Comment: _"..all type of DBMS.."_ - that may be **too broad** a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the interfaces instead of the concrete classes, for example [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `SqlConnection`. Then you just need a class which returns the interfaces by using the concrete types(f.e. a `IDataReader` or `IDbCommand`).

For example:

```
public class DB
{
    public enum Provider { 
        SqlServer, MySql, Oracle//, ...
    }

    public DB()
    {
        this.CurrentProvider = Properties.Settings.Default.Provider; // presuming that you have this setting
    }

    public Provider CurrentProvider { get; set; }

    public IDbConnection NewConnection()
    {
        switch (this.CurrentProvider) { 
            case Provider.SqlServer:
                return new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
            case Provider.MySql:
                return new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
                // ...
            default: throw new NotSupportedException(CurrentProvider.ToString());
        }
    }

    //  and other methods ....
}
```

On this way only this class needs to know the current dbms. Of course you have to use standard sql and cannot use database specific methods like `Row_Number`.